# Import path in Java, Maven

Tags: java, maven

Following the tutorial about Kafka Streams located at: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroExample.java

There is a line:

```
import io.confluent.examples.streams.avro.WikiFeed
```

As I suppose it relates to this file: https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent/examples/streams/wikifeed.avsc

- How does Maven knows it is in `resource` not `java` folder?
- Why *io/confluent/examples/streams/**avro**/wikifeed.avsc* instead of ***avro***/io/confluent/examples/streams/wikifeed.avsc?

The other import is even more fantastic:

```
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig;
```

- There is no `kafka` folder in the `java/io/confluent` folder.

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/tree/4.0.0-post/src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent.

How does all this magic suppose to work?

Comment: @IanMcLaird in this case, maven is not downloading anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *magic* is made by [avro-maven-plugin](https://github.com/phunt/avro-maven-plugin) which you can find in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/pom.xml):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
    <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${avro.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>schema</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent/examples/streams</sourceDirectory>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                <stringType>String</stringType>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Quoting from the documentation of the plugin:

> Simple integration with dynamic languages. Code generation is not required to read or write data files nor to use or implement RPC protocols. Code generation as an optional optimization, only worth implementing for statically typed languages.

This is, at pre compile time, the plugin reads the content of *avsc* files and generate binary sources (for this case, Java classes) that then can be used in the code.

You can see the code generated by the plugin in `target/generated-sources`. There will be a folder structure and proper java (not class) files there.

Answer (score 1):

The `WikiFeed` class is created dynamically at build time using the `avro-maven-plugin` from the .avsc file you linked to. You can check how it's configured [in the `<plugins>` section of pom.xml](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.0.0-post/pom.xml#L346-L363).

The `AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig` class comes from the `kafka-avro-serializer` dependency. Eclipse has a nice way of navigating from the individual class in the Editor view back to the Package Explorer which includes the Maven dependencies, like this:

[image: package explorer: maven dependencies]